# How to use a Gyroscope to move an NSObject around the screen

Tags: ios, accelerometer, move, nsobject, gyroscope

I have an NSObject ball, that I would like to move in the direction you tilt the iPhone. I've never done anything with tilting before, only touch. I'd also like for it to move faster when tilted at a steeper angle. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

That is the code I use albeit with very poor results: you might want to test it and check what might be improved:

```
NSDate * lastDate=nil;

-(void)didRotate:(CMRotationRate)rotationRate{
NSDate *newDate=[NSDate date];
CGPoint testCenter=[[[OverlayViewController sharedOverlay] testElement] center];
if (lastDate!=nil){
    NSLog(@"rotate x %f y %f, z %f", rotationRate.x, rotationRate.y, rotationRate.z);
    NSTimeInterval interval=[newDate timeIntervalSinceDate:lastDate];
    CGRect topFrame=[[[OverlayViewController sharedOverlay] view] frame];
    float xAtan=atan(rotationRate.x);
    float yAtan=atan(rotationRate.y);

    float xRotation= topFrame.size.width*xAtan/interval;
    float yRotation=topFrame.size.height*yAtan/interval;
    NSLog(@"topHeight=%f yAtan=%f interval=%f yRotation=%f", topFrame.size.height, yAtan, interval, yRotation);
    NSLog(@"interval %f rotation (%f,%f)", interval, xRotation, yRotation);
    CGPoint newCenter=CGPointMake(testCenter.x+xRotation, testCenter.y+yRotation);
    NSLog(@"old center (%f,%f) new center (%f,%f)", testCenter.x, testCenter.y, newCenter.x, newCenter.y);
    [[[OverlayViewController sharedOverlay] testElement] setCenter:newCenter];
}
lastDate=newDate;
}
```